# Gráficos de coluna (Bootstrap)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que precisa exibir gráficos de colunas.

O sistema esta usando Bootsrap e MVC 4 C#.

Alguém sabe me dizer se há algum framework para criação de gráficos?

Comment: Você pode usar http://www.highcharts.com/ ou Google Charts

Answer (score 1):

Tem um presente no próprio [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) que faz gráficos de colunas facilmente ([ele também possui os outros modelos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). No [System.Web.Helpers.Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.chart%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) você cria uma instância e trabalha com os dados nessa *class*.

**Exemplo:**

*Na sua View coloque esse trecho de código:*

```cs
<img src="@Url.Action("Imagem", "Estudo")" border="0" />
```

*E no Controller esse método:*

```cs
public void Imagem()
{
    ICollection<Grafico> grafico = new List<Grafico>(){
        new Grafico(){ Titulo = "Campo 1", Soma = 500M},
        new Grafico(){ Titulo = "Campo 2", Soma = 100M},
        new Grafico(){ Titulo = "Campo 3", Soma = 200M},
        new Grafico(){ Titulo = "Campo 4", Soma = 300M},
        new Grafico(){ Titulo = "Campo 5", Soma = 400M},
        new Grafico(){ Titulo = "Campo 5", Soma = 100M}
    };      

    System.Web.Helpers.Chart ch = 
                new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(500, 400, ChartTheme.Blue);
    ch.AddSeries(
        name: "Campo",
        chartType: "Column",
        axisLabel: "Campo",
        xField: "Campo",
        yFields: "Soma",
        xValue: grafico.Select(x => x.Titulo).ToArray(),
        yValues: grafico.Select(x => x.Soma).ToArray()
        ).AddLegend();

    ch.ToWebImage()
        .Write();
}
```

***Resultado:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Com [DotNet.Highcharts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNet.Highcharts/), baixe o pacote de instalação pelo [Package Manage Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console), com o comando:

```cs
PM> Install-Package DotNet.Highcharts
```

*Na View:*

**Obs:** *Configure sua View dessa maneira.*

```cs
@model DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Grafico</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        @(Model)
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*No Controller esse método:*

```cs
public ActionResult Grafico()
{
    ICollection<Grafico> grafico = new List<Grafico>(){
        new Grafico(){ Titulo = "Campo 1", Soma = 500M},
        new Grafico(){ Titulo = "Campo 2", Soma = 100M},
        new Grafico(){ Titulo = "Campo 3", Soma = 200M},
        new Grafico(){ Titulo = "Campo 4", Soma = 300M},
        new Grafico(){ Titulo = "Campo 5", Soma = 400M},
        new Grafico(){ Titulo = "Campo 6", Soma = 100M}
    };

    DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
    .InitChart(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Chart
    {
        DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column,
        MarginRight = 130,
        MarginBottom = 25,
        ClassName = "chart"
    })
    .SetXAxis(new XAxis
    {
        Categories = grafico.Select(x => x.Titulo).ToArray()
    }).SetSeries(new Series
    {
        Data = new Data(grafico.Select(x => (object)x.Soma).ToArray())
    });
    chart.SetTitle(new Title() { Text = "Campos" });
    chart.SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions() { Bar = new PlotOptionsBar() { ShowInLegend = true, Visible = true } });            

    return View(chart);
}
```

***Resultado:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Tem alguns. Vou colocar pra você alguns deles:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNet.Highcharts/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Highcharts.Net/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/HighCharts/

Ou, ainda, a seguinte lista de pacotes pode ser útil:

https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=charts